# Intuition for differentials given two constraint equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was the set the question below and would really appreciate some intuition with regards to geometry and the differentials.

"Consider the curve of points $(x, y, z)$ satisfying $x^5 + yz = 3$ and $xy^2 + yz^2+ zx^2 = 7$. Use the method of total differentials to find $dx/dy$ at $(x, y, z) = (1,1,2)$."

Using the suggestion for total derivatives I found the formulae $5dx + 2dy + dz = 0$ and $5dx + 6dy + 5dz = 0$, and by substituting $dz$ found that $dx = -dy/5$ and so $dx/dy = -1/5$, which is correct.

However, I am really struggling to see why this is "allowed" so to speak, and it may regard my understanding of differentials. Why is it possible to substitute for $dz$ in these formulae? In doing this am I taking $z$ to be dependent on $x$ and $y$? Geometrically this could be viewed as the curve of intersection of two surfaces, so am I taking $x$ and $z$ to be dependent on $y$ and independent of each other?

I realise this is possibly an ill-posed question, but any help or intuition would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm entirely clear about your question, but in a linear $2×3$ system, you can always eliminate one of the variables. That's what you just did. As for the geometric interpretation -- yes, you may consider the system as defining the point $(x,y)$ as a function of $z.$ Then the ratio $\mathrm dx/\mathrm dy$ gives you the slope of the curve at that point.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid it is quite difficult for me to explain. Perhaps a better way of wording it might be that I'm unsure intuitively why $dx/dy$ is a total derivative rather than a partial. I can see that it would be possible to substitute z in one of the equations and therefore compute this total derivative, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why x is simply a function of y along this curve, if the curve is in 3d space. If y has been chosen as the independent variable, are both x and z dependent only on y along this curve?

Comment: Actually, I interpreted the system as defining a plane curve, by taking $z$ as a parameter, and $x$ and $y$ as functions of $z.$ As for your question, these are not partial differentials by the way you computed them. But more to the point, you can see that $x,y$ are functions of $z.$